# ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I am working on a basic app called PhotoApp, where I am learning how to set up SMTP with rails. I have used basic Ruby with SMTP sometime ago, and I know my email works, just the emails sent gets to spam folder.

But when I am trying to configure SMTP on Rails, I am getting `ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name):`, and that's the primary reason why the app, when pushed to heroku, crashed every time a user signs up.

[image: Error Image]

---

Here's my config/environments/development.rb:

```rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:8080' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'example.net',
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'gmail_email',
  password: '...'
}

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I am running the server on localhost:8080, in development mode, so my host is set to localhost:8080.

Apart from that I am not able to get my app working with my gmail username with SMTP in rails.

Edit, this ruby code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'net/smtp'

message = <<~EOF
    From: mygmail@gmail.com
    To: someone@protonmail.com
    Subject: Hello!

    Hello!
        #{"HELLO ".*(50).delete_suffix(?\s)}
EOF

Net::SMTP.new('smtp.gmail.com', 587).tap(&:enable_starttls_auto).start('gmail.com', 'mygmail@gmail.com', 'mygmailpass', :plain) do |smtp|
    smtp.send_message message, 'mygmail@gmail.com', 'someone@protonmail.com'
end
```

But as a newbie to rails, I can't get actionmailer working when the same email is used in the config file...

Comment: `user_name` should be a gmail address. e.g. `abcdexample@gmail.com` and password would be the password of that gmail address

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Did you restart the server after the change?

Comment: Yes, I did that, too

Comment: I think this is a bug, because everything is setup properly, and `Rails.application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[:user_name]` also returns my email address.

Comment: Stupid error caused by sendgrid. Sendgrid was overriding the values from environment.rb. It's solved by simply removing the stmp_settings from environment.rb